# How to auto-start locating when map loads with leaflet locatecontrol?

Tags: typescript, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to make a custom React component that uses the leaflet.locatecontrol to provide location features with my leaflet map.

So far I have it working completely fine as a standard control. It's on my map, if I tap the locate icon locating starts. If I tap the locate icon again locating stops.

What I want, however, is to remember whether locating is on or off and restore that state (in sessionStorage) so I can use it to auto-start locating the next time the user visits the map. I cannot figure out how to do this.

Here's my component:

```
import * as L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet.locatecontrol";
import "leaflet.locatecontrol/dist/L.Control.Locate.css";
import { EffectCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useMap } from "react-leaflet";

interface ILocateControlProps extends L.Control.LocateOptions {
  autoStart?: boolean;
}

const LocateControl = (props: ILocateControlProps) => {
  const { autoStart, ...rest } = props;
  const [savedAutoLocateState] = useState(() => {
    const storedValue = sessionStorage.getItem("autoLocate");
    if (!storedValue) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return sessionStorage.getItem("autoLocate") === "true";
    }
  });
  const map = useMap();

  map?.addEventListener("locateactivate", (e) => {
    sessionStorage.setItem("autoLocate", "true");
  });
  map?.addEventListener("locatedeactivate", (e) => {
    sessionStorage.setItem("autoLocate", "false");
  });

  useEffect((): ReturnType<EffectCallback> => {
    const instance = new L.Control.Locate({
      ...rest,
    });

    map.addControl(instance);

    return () => {
      map.removeControl(instance);
    };
  }, [map, rest]);

  return null;
};

export default LocateControl;
```

There's a `start()` method on `instance` that will do what I want, but if I call it after adding `map.addControl(instance)` I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'options')
    at NewClass._isOutsideMapBounds (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40048:24)
    at NewClass.setView (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39767:16)
    at NewClass._onLocationFound (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39980:16)
    at NewClass.fire (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40694:16)
    at NewClass._handleGeolocationResponse (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:43586:12)
```

I assume this means the map is somehow not ready, but I can't for the life of me figure out why or how else I would trigger this to start at the appropriate time.

Any tips or thoughts would be appreciated!